# Codeigniter pagination issue with uri_segment

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

this is how my url looks,
http://example.com/Admin/uploadQuestionsForSections/1/2 (fourth segment is the page number for pagination. 3rd segment is the id). Problem is , clicking on pagination links dont serve up the correct records. All pages show the same records. I have provided below the pagination configuration:

```
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'Admin/uploadQuestionsForSections/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['total_rows'] = $allcount;
$config['per_page'] = $rowperpage;
```

==

However it doesn't work. Help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain *how* it doesn't work? That makes it easier to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Hello, I meant, i am able to see same initial set of results from db , doesn't matter on which page I am..

Comment: Not sure if this could be a factor, but you can always include the `controller/method/` part within the `base_url()` ... it looks cleaner and you can still add segments 3+ later. `base_url('admin/uploadQuestionsForSections').$this-uri->segment(3).'/'.$this->uri->segment(4);` for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url($this->uri->uri_string().'/');
```

Comment: thank you for responding. I will try and let you know..however, can you explain, what exactly this does?

Comment: Its a general solution for base_url that you don't need to write it down yourself everytime you use pagination and added a slash to the end of it cause you will need it .. let me know if it worked and if it doesn't we will explore what else you might did wrong.

Comment: Then i guess maybe its not a pagination problem, maybe there is a problem with your controller or model function so please update your question and show us you method!

Comment: this is how it goes:
==calling the method in controller==
$trans_record = $this->Common_model->getData($rowno,$rowperpage,$arrPost,$this->uri->segment(3));

===in model======

public function getData($rowno,$rowperpage,$arrPost="",$sec_id) {
 
 $this->db->select('id, qustion');
    $this->db->from('gk_questions');
    $this->db->WHERE('section_id', $sec_id);
    if($arrPost){
  $this->transactionQuery($arrPost);
    }
 $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
    $this->db->limit($rowperpage, $rowno); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
   
  }